# JComponent.setVisible() does not successfully hide separator on OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing, jcomponent, jpopupmenu

In a class which extends JMenu, I have created a new JPopupMenu.Separator object and added it to the menu:

```
if (separator == null)
    {
        separator = new JPopupMenu.Separator()
        this.add(separator);
    }
```

Then, in various places where things are added to/removed from the menu, I call a method `updateSeparatorVisibility` defined like this:

```
private void updateSeparatorVisibility()
{
    if (separator != null)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                // vis is some public boolean
                separator.setVisible(vis);
            }
        });

        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

This will be called while the menu is closed and when I reopen the menu, I expect to see changes in the visibility of the separator.

On Windows, this works just fine. On Mac, the separator will change from invisible to visible when desired, but will not change back to invisible afterwards. In fact, I was previously seeing the visibility change with about a 50% probability. This no longer seems to be the case after adding the `invokeLater`, `revalidate` and `repaint`, all of which were recommended in various other StackOverflow posts but have not fixed the problem.

I have put a lot of logging in and the code definitely calls `setVisible` when it should and `vis` has the expected value - I just don't see this reflected in the behaviour of the menu.

What is wrong with my code and why is it platform dependent?

Comment: Try putting revalidate() and repaint() inside the invokeLater().

Comment: Why not simply remove the seperator if it is not supposed to be shown?

Comment: Because I want to be able to turn it off and on depending on an option in settings. Theoretically, this should be more sensible than removing it and re-adding it at the correct position every time I toggle it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `boolean vis` field may be `public`, but "The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation *happens-before* the read operation." Make the field `volatile`, because "A write to a volatile field *happens-before* every subsequent read of that same field." See [*Memory Consistency Properties*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) for details.

Comment: I probably should be doing this as you say, but I know from logging that the boolean does take the correct value when we enter the EDT.